# How to export class constructor in c++ DLL project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I'm building a `dll` project in Visual Studio 2013. My header file for class definition is as follows:

```
#ifndef PREPROCESSOR_H
#define PREPROCESSOR_H

#ifndef MAKEDLL
    #define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include "common.h"

class DLLEXPORT Preprocessor
{
public: 
    Preprocessor();
    ...
private:
    ...
};
```

After building it, I called this class from another project. I've included its header file, generated dll and .lib files. But I got a `LNK2001` error for my `main.obj` file:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Preprocessor::Preprocessor (void)" (??0Preprocessor@@QEAA@XZ
```

What did I wrong here?? Thank you.

Comment: should you put DLLEXPORT in constructor declaration?

Comment: You have to link the import library of the DLL project.  Project + Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies setting.  And fix that typo.

Comment: @PeterK: that doesn't change the error.

Comment: @HansPassant: I've added the .lib file in my Linker->Input->Additional Deependencies, together with its folder address into Linker->General->Additional Library Directories.

Comment: Why downvote? Anyone who downvoted my question, please specify a reason so that I can make improvement.

Comment: Erm, wait, there's something else very wrong.  The constructor of a C++ class is never `__cdecl`, it must be `__thiscall`.  Very hard to guess how you did that.  A minimum repro project is needed to see the mistake.

Comment: So I'll ask the silly question: Did you make sure `MAKEDLL` is *defined* for your DLL project, and **not** defined for your consuming project ? Both can be examined under Project Properties|Configuration Properties|C/C++|Preprocessor, for each project respectively.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I can make sure of it.

Comment: @HansPassant: I didn't fully get it.